# Check for int overflow in C++

Tags: c++, integer, integer-overflow

I'm running a C++ program which adds numbers in a for loop:

```
int y = 0;
for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
  int pow = 1;
  for (int j=0 j<i; j++) {
    pow *= 10;
  }
  y+= vec[i]*pow; // where vec is a vector of digits
}
```

but I am not sure how to check if an overflow has occured. Is there a way?

Comment: As an aside, you can improve your algorithm from quadratic to linear by keeping the last value of `pow` and multiplying it by 10 only once each iteration.

Comment: indeed that would make more sense, thanks

Comment: useful? [How to detect integer overflow in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow)

Answer (score 3):

As Peter rightly [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186373/841108), **overflow is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** in *standard* C++11 (or C99), and you really should be [afraid of UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

However, some compilers give you extensions to deal and detect integer overflow.

If you can restrict yourself to a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, you could use its [integer overflow builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html).

You could also restrict yourself to `int32_t` and compute arithmetic in `int64_t` and check against result above `INT32_MAX` or below `INT32_MIN`. This would be probably slower (but more portable) than using compiler specific extensions. BTW some compilers also have some `__int128_t` type (so you could compute arithmetic in `__int128_t` and check likewise that the result fits in `int64_t`).

If your goal is to have [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), better use some exising bignum library, like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) (because *efficient* bignum arithmetic needs very clever algorithms).

Answer (score 2):

Overflow of a signed integral variable results in undefined behaviour.  A consequence is that, once overflow has occurred, it cannot be reliably detected in standard C++.   Any behaviour is permitted.   So your implementation (compiler, library, toolset, etc) may provide a specific means to detect integer overflow - but that means will not necessarily work with other implementations.

The only ways are to check for potential overflows before doing operations (or a sequence of operations).   Or to design your approach (e.g. pick limits) to prevent overflow occurring.

Answer (score 1):

There are different options and probably no one that suits every situation and need.

For example in this situation you could check that if `pow` is less or equal to `INT_MAX/10` before multiplying. This works because `INT_MAX/10` is the largest number such that it times 10 will be at most `INT_MAX`. Note that the compiler would normally precompute the `INT_MAX/10` if you insert it into the code (otherwise you could put it in a local variable if it bothers you):

```
int y = 0;
for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
  int pow = 1;
  for (int j=0 j<i; j++) {
    if( pow > INT_MAX/10 )
       throw OverflowException;
    pow *= 10;
  }
  y+= vec[i]*pow; // where vec is a vector of digits
}
```

This solution has the disadvantage that if the other factor is not constant the compiler (and you) can't reasonably avoid the division `INT_MAX/n` to be done at runtime (and division is normally more expensive than multiplication).

Another possibility is that you could do the calculation in a wider type. For example:

```
int y = 0;
for (int i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
  int32_t pow = 1;
  for (int j=0 j<i; j++) {
    int64_t tmp = (int64_t)pow * (int64_t)10;

    if( tmp > (int64_t)INT32_MAX )
         raise OverflowException;

    pow = (int32_t)tmp;
  }
  y+= vec[i]*pow; // where vec is a vector of digits
}
```

This have the disadvantage that first a wider type might not be available, and if it is it may require software implementation of the multiplication (for example 64-bit on 32-bit systems) which means slower multiplication.

Another situation is where you add two integers. If overflow occurs the result will be less than both integers, especially if they're both positive the result will be negative.