# Reverse an integer in leetcode

Tags: c++, overflow

I was trying to solve the reverse integer problem, where we have to keep in mind to deal with overflow.

Reading others solutions and tried out, I wrote my solution

```
class Solution {
public:
  int reverse(int x) {
  int result = 0;
  int old_result = 0;
  while(x) {
    old_result = result;
    result = result*10 + x%10;
    if ((result-old_result*10)!=x%10)
        return 0;
    x = x/10;
  }
  return result;
  }
};
```

And the answer was not accepted because overflow was not handled well. It turned out changing

```
if ((result-old_result*10)!=x%10)
```

to

```
if ((result-x%10)/10!=old_result)
```

would make things work.

I feel these lines are doing the same check. Not sure why one passes and one fails.

Can anyone help explain?

Answer (score 1):

> I feel these lines are doing the same check. Not sure why one passes and one fails.

Not necessarily. If the value of `old_result` ever was more than (or equal to) `std::numeric_limits<int>::max () / 10 + 1`, the expression `old_result*10` would overflow, which would give you the wrong answer.

Overflow of integral types are undefined behavior. This is the quite from C++ (C++11/C++14/C++17) standard draft (I don't have access for the full version of standard, and, in majority of cases, it is good enough):

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
>   representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

The second form (reordered) of `if` removes the multiplication - effectively increasing the range of values, that can be used in `old_result`.

Comment: @chux My bad. I thought wrong (was trying to find definitive answer for this in C++ standard (for C++11, C++14, and C++17), and, apparently, I am not used to reading it, yet). Will update my answer.

Comment: @chux What I meant is, that I was trying to find the definitive answer, _after_ you pointed this out to me (and was searching for the relevant quote for all this time).

Comment: "The second form (reordered) of if removes the multiplication", but too late.  The prior `result*10` may overflow, rendering  subsequent code of no certain value.

Comment: @chux Yes, you are correct. Due to the fact that OP mentioned that _second form_ started working correctly, I didn't pay enough attention to the actual code, but, rather, looked at the differences between those statements. So, due to those mistakes, I guess that it's time to rest for me :/

Comment: Thanks for the spec lookup

Answer (score 1):

```
   result = result*10 + x%10;

   if ((result-old_result*10)!=x%10)
   // or
   if ((result-x%10)/10!=old_result)
```

Both are bad when coded after `result*10 + x%10;` as the overflow may already have happened.

`int` overflow is to be avoided for well behaved code.

Rather than depend on overflow behaving as certain way, detect if `result*10 + x%10` will overflow before computing it.

```
  // for positive numbers
  int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max
  while(x) {
    int digit = x%10;
    if (result >= max/10 && (result > max/10 || digit > max%10)) {
      Overflow();
    }
    result = result*10 + digit;
    x = x/10;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that overflow with signed numbers is <strike>implementation specific</strike> UB, so I suggest to use `unsigned` instead. Then considering that it use similar property than unsigned, and assuming that `result = result*10 + x%10;` overflows. Then:

```
result -= old_result * 10;
```

"reverts" the overflow in the same way.

whereas the following is true

```
(result - x % 10) == old_result * 10; // With possible overflow in both side.
```

Dividing by `10` on both side removes the overflow only with the simplification

```
(result - x % 10) / 10 == old_result;
// overflow on left side (before division). No overflow on right side.
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33186429/2410359) indicates overflow with signed numbers is undefined.  So is it "implementation specific" or undefined?